# Writing a regex in JavaScript to match $ variable prefix syntax (like found in Bash scripts)

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3, regex-group

I'm trying to write a regular expression in JavaScript to search a multi-line bash script and extract all the variable names. I can neither seem to figure it out myself nor find a script that does exactly what I need.

I've gotten this far:

```
var re = /(?:^|\W)\$(\w+)(?!\w)/g;
var s = "test $test1 testagain$test2 testyetagain $test3 $test4$test5";
var matches = [];
while (match = re.exec(s)) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
```

This will give me "test1", "test3", and "test4". But I would also like to get "test2" and "test5".

It would also be great if there were a way I could get "\$" to NOT match if it appears in the string. In other words, is there a way to escape the "$" string in the text so that it is ignored by my regular expression? So in case "\$1.00" appeared in the text, it would *not* match "1" as the above regex does now.

Thanks in advance for any help or for pointing me in the right direction.

PS This is actually for Action Script 3 but anything that works in JavaScript pre-ES6 should work in AS 3.

PPS The final goal is to replace these matches with variables from a key-value hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could repeatedly match `\$` (in which case do nothing) or `$\w+` (in which case, it's an unescaped dollar sign indicating the start of a variable you want to match). Use a replacer function to decide whether to leave the match alone, or replace with whatever other string you want:

```js
const replacements = {
  test1: 'testone',
  test2: 'testtwo',
  test3: 'testthree',
  test4: 'testfour',
  test5: 'testfive'
};
var s = "test $test1 testagain$test2 testyetagain $test3 $test4$test5 \\$1.00";
const result = s.replace(
  /\\\$|\$(\w+)/g,
  (match, g1) => match === '\\$'
    ? match // replace with the matched string - in other words, leave it unchanged
    : replacements[g1]
);
console.log(result);
```

On newer engines, you could negative lookbehind for a backslash instead, which makes the logic a lot easier, but it's *not* a good cross-browser solution, since it'll only work in new environments:

```js
const replacements = {
  test1: 'testone',
  test2: 'testtwo',
  test3: 'testthree',
  test4: 'testfour',
  test5: 'testfive'
};
var s = "test $test1 testagain$test2 testyetagain $test3 $test4$test5 \\$1.00";
const result = s.replace(
  /(?<!\\)\$(\w+)/g,
  (_, g1) => replacements[g1]
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm picking this answer for the first solution but with a few caveats. First, I needed to adjust the lambda so it would work in AS3 (pre-ES6 ECMA4 standard). I also found that it wanted to return "\\$" instead of simply "$" which I fixed easily in the replace function: const result = s.replace(
    /\\\$|\$(\w+)/g, function(match, g1, index, complete):String {
     return match === '\\$' ? "$" : "blorch";
    }
   );

Comment: Finally, it would be nice if I could use simply a "\$" in my string and/or text files to escape the "$" symbol instead of the double "\\$". But I haven't got that to work yet. I can live with myself if I have to do "\\$" for now.

Comment: You can use `String.raw` in a Javascript string literal if you want to avoid having to double-escape backslashes, if that's what you're looking for, ``String.raw`foo\bar` === 'foo\\bar'``

Comment: That's an awesome suggestion. But again, this isn't actually Javascript. It's Action Script 3, so I don't have String.raw. I do use Javascript elsewhere though, so it's a great feature to know about!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex

```
(?<!\\)\$([^\W$]+)
```

- `(?<!\\)` - Negative lookbehind to avoid `\$` to match
- `\$` - Matches `$`
- `([^\W$]+)` - Match anything except word non word character and $

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6RyWfy/1/)

Comment: This is a great answer and the only reason I didn't pick it is because CertainPerformance also addressed my need to be able to escape the "$" sign as necessary. But still, I just wanted to say I really love this answer and its graphical explanation. Thank you!

Comment: A sorry, my browser was cached from last night and I see you included the negative look behind for the $. I don't think negative look behind works in Javascript before ES5 (ie ECMA 4 / AS3). Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

This expression

```
(?:\\{2,}\$[0-9.]+)|\$([^$\s]+)
```

collects the undesired data using a non-capturing group

```
(?:\\{2,}\$[0-9.]+)
```

and returns the desired data using a capturing group

```
([^$\s]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6MpmnD/1/)

```js
const regex = /(?:\\{2,}\$[0-9.]+)|\$([^$\s]+)/g;
const str = `test \$test1 testagain\$test2 testyetagain \$test3 \$test4\$test5 \\\\\$1.00 \\\\\\\\\\\\\$1.00

`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: This is good, but I think you misunderstood my intention with "$1.00". I used money as just an real-world example of when it would be desirable to escape the "$" but I want to actually be able to escape it regardless of whether it's followed by digits. Thank you for the visual, though. That greatly helped my comprehension!

Answer (score 2):

Try matching `(?:\\\$\w+)|\$(\w+)`. Since the first group starts matching earlier, it will finish matching first; however as a non-capturing block, won't be returned.

```js
var re = /(?:\\\$\w+)|\$(\w+)/g;
var s = "test $test1 testagain$test2 testyetagain $test3 $test4$test5\\$1.00";
var matches = [];
while (match = re.exec(s)) {
  match[1] && matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: This is a great answer also, but when I implement replace, I end up with ".00" instead of "$1.00". Though the other matches can be replaced correctly. This may be a quirk to AS3.

Comment: Thinking about it, it is possibly replacing the whole match, not the group[1]. The regex still matches `\$1.00` (matching `\$1` since the . isn't matched by the \w metacharacter.) However, the group[1] for the match will be undefined.

Comment: Interesting, so I could test against group1 value to determine if it's the escaped "$" or not. And you are right, as I continued working with this, I started matching $1 as though that were the variable. I'm ok with my current solution since it allows me to move forward, but I'd love to revisit this answer and refine my solution in the future.

Comment: Similar to the chosen solution, you could use a replacement function like `function(match, g1) { return g1 && replacement(g1) || match; }`